# Rotating projectile in direction it is moving

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, mathematics, projectile-physics

I am using a parabola curve to launch my arrows:

```
public static Vector3 Parabola(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, float height, float t)
{
    Func<float, float> f = x => -4 * height * x * x + 4 * height * x;

    var mid = Vector3.Lerp(start, end, t);

    return new Vector3(mid.x, f(t) + Mathf.Lerp(start.y, end.y, t), mid.z);
}
```

I have a projectile that is a simple capsule scaled down to be long and thin like an arrow. I've tried every way to rotate it I could find online, but there is always something off. In order to follow the curve I need the direction between the last position and the new position, so I have been trying things like:

```
void ParabolaMovement() //Called in Update()
{
    parabolaAnim += Time.deltaTime;

    parabolaAnim = parabolaAnim % 5;

    Vector3 newPos = MathParabola.Parabola(start, target, 5f, parabolaAnim / 5);
    Vector3 dir = newPos - transform.position;
    transform.LookAt(dir);

    transform.position = newPos;
}
```

As for what is going wrong, it does not point AT the target, which I udnerstand it can't because nowhere do I specify target pos, which I should, but don't know where. I cannot simply tell it to lookat target, since I want it to lookat the direction it is currently going in the curve, but it also needs to face the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing

```
transform.LookAt(dir);
```

to

```
transform.LookAt(newPos);
```

should work, atleast under the assumption that the forward vector of the arrow is set up correctly.

Comment: ... That did it. Feels nice to have spent 5 hours on trying to figure that one out. thanks!